# How to open a terminal prompt in an existing window in vim

Tags: vim

To open a new Terminal session in vim I can do:

`:term`

However, this opens the terminal in a new tab. Is it possible, to have the terminal replace the section/frame and not open a new one in vim?

---

**Update**: It seems like this is the correct answer, on the vim site: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/17306/28904